# Tag object being changed dynamically by displaying html from a code editor

Tags: javascript, html

Hello stackoverflow community, I have a question regarding the use of the `<object>` html tag. Below is a description of what I want to do:

I am using the summernote editor, however I would like every change within the editor to be presented to the user as the html page will be. I am currently using the following code:

```js
$('#summernote').summernote({
            placeholder: 'Hello bootstrap 4',
            tabsize: 2,
            height: 300,
            lang: 'pt-BR'
        });
        $("#summernote").on("summernote.change", function(e) { // callback as jquery custom event 
            console.log('it is changed');
            myFunction();
        });

        var i = 0;
        var dragging = false;
        $('#dragbar').mousedown(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            dragging = true;
            var main = $('#main');
            var ghostbar = $('<div>', {
                id: 'ghostbar',
                css: {
                    height: main.outerHeight(),
                    top: main.offset().top,
                    left: main.offset().left
                }
            }).appendTo('body');

            $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
                ghostbar.css("left", e.pageX + 2);
            });

        });

        $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
            if (dragging) {
                var percentage = (e.pageX / window.innerWidth) * 100;
                var mainPercentage = 100 - percentage;

                $('#console').text("side:" + percentage + " main:" + mainPercentage);

                $('#sidebar').css("width", percentage + "%");
                $('#main').css("width", mainPercentage + "%");
                $('#ghostbar').remove();
                $(document).unbind('mousemove');
                dragging = false;
            }
        });

        function myFunction(data) {
            var text = $('#summernote').summernote('code');
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><meta charset='UTF-8'>" + text + "</html>"; 
            console.log(document.getElementById("demo"));
            console.log(text);
        }
```

```css
.clearfix:after {
            content: '';
            display: table;
            clear: both;
        }

        #main {
            float: right;
            width: 50%;
        }

        #sidebar {
            width: 50%;
            float: left;
            overflow-y: hidden;
        }

        #dragbar {
            /*background-color: #a9a9a9;*/
            background: transparent;
            height: 100%;
            float: right;
            width: 3px;
            cursor: col-resize;
        }

        #ghostbar {
            width: 3px;
            background-color: #a9a9a9;
            opacity: 0.5;
            position: absolute;
            cursor: col-resize;
            z-index: 999
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Summernote Editor</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.9/summernote-bs4.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.9/summernote-bs4.js"></script>
    <script src="summernote-pt-BR.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <!--<div id="summernote"></div>-->
            <div id="sidebar" class="col">
                <span id="position"></span>
                <div id="dragbar">
                </div>
                sidebar
                <form method="post">
                    <textarea id="summernote" name="editordata"></textarea>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
                </form>
            </div>
           <div id="main">main 
               <p id="demo"></p>                
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

But instead of using the `<p>` tag along with innerHtml, I'd like to use the `<object>` tag, and its contents being changed daily.
If you have other better solutions, feel free to make suggestions.

Note: I have already tried using the  tag but somehow using this tag hinders the resize that I need to perform between the editor and html viewer.

Note 2: I'm a beginner, and my English is not good. So sorry if something went wrong without making sense. I used Google translate to explain the issue.

Comment: Hi Rafael — what features do you want to gain by using an object or iframe tag that you do not already have? You are already dynamically rendering the HTML generated by summernote in your p element. What isn't working that you'd like to be working?

Comment: Is that when I save the html code of the editor, and I open it another time, the appearance is not the same as when I use the <p> tag. When I use <iframe> or <object>, this does not happen.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Rafael — thanks for clarifying.

The reason your code looks different in the iframe or object tags is due to the differing CSS. When you use an iframe and set the source dynamically, the CSS comes from the User Agent Stylesheet. The tag does not inherit the parent's styles. Currently, your CSS in the p tag is from Bootstrap 4.

Option 1: You could customize the CSS on this element to make it appear consistent in a non-Bootstrap context.

Option 2: If you still want to change tags, I think you are better off using an [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) instead of an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object) tag, per the MDN docs and the discussion on [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30221703/using-object-tag-to-include-html-content-allowed-format-of-included-file).

Change `<p id="demo"></p>` to `<iframe id="demo"></iframe>`, and your `myFunction` to:

```
function myFunction(data) {
  var text = $('#summernote').summernote('code');            
  var frame=document.getElementById("demo");
  frame.srcdoc="<!DOCTYPE html><html><meta charset='UTF-8'>" + text + "</html>"; 
}
```

If you support IE11, Edge, and Opera Mini ([srcdoc is not supported there](https://caniuse.com/#feat=iframe-srcdoc)) you can use a [polyfill](https://github.com/jugglinmike/srcdoc-polyfill).

One final consideration with this route is performance — I couldn't find much on this, but I suspect that setting the innerHTML of your p tag is far less expensive than re-rendering an iframe. You might want to investigate and consider reducing the update interval if this becomes a problem.